# Is this a bug on Visual Studio or AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, designer, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4.

This is a CLR Project (.NET Framework 4.5).

I'm not sure about the origin of this bug, so I cannot fill in a bug report to its respective program.

I either found a bug on `Visual Studio Community 2019` or `AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer`. When adding a custom control derived from `AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer` in the `Designer`, if you switch the `Language` of the `form` by the `Designer` then it gets all blank and you are forced to close the `Designer`. For another custom controls like derived from `System::Windows::Forms::*` that bug doesn't happen.

This is my ClassLibrary1.dll e.g:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    [System::ComponentModel::ToolboxItem(true)]
    public ref class MyMediaPlayer : public AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer
    {
    public:
        MyMediaPlayer() {}
    };
}
```

Comment: You can try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=61).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved on version 16.8.6. So it was actually a Visual Studio bug.